# Adjoints preserve limits (resp. colimits) Do they preserves completeness (resp. cocompleteness)?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I know that left adjoints preserve colimits and right adjoints preserve limits.
So clearly if the limits (resp. colimits) in both categories exist, the adjoints map them to each other.

My question is, whether it's garantueed that the limit  exists?

To be more precise: Let $T\colon A\rightarrow B$ a functor that is a right (resp. left) adjoint of some functor and $D\colon I\rightarrow A$ a diagramn, such that it's limit (resp. colimit) (in $A$) exists. Does the limit (resp. colimt) $T\circ D$ always exist?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and this is *precisely* the statement that $T$ preserves limits! If $\{L \to D\}$ is a limit cone, and $T$ preserves limits, then $\{T(L) \to T \circ D\}$ is a limit cone.

Comment: Thank you. I was only aware of the "preserveness" if both limits do exist.